# Report queue size using prometheus client_ruby client

Tags: ruby, prometheus

I'm trying to export the size of an internal queue. I don't want to maintain  a gauge counter, using incr/decr. What I need is to retrieve the actual queue size at the scrap moment. Is that possible using the prometheus ruby client?

Comment: A queue of what? your question is vague.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your vague question would be probably yes. A look at the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/#features) shows:

#### Overview

- a multi-dimensional data model with time series data identified by metric name and key/value pairs
- a flexible query language to leverage this dimensionality
- no reliance on distributed storage; single server nodes are autonomous
- time series collection happens via a pull model over HTTP
- pushing time series is supported via an intermediary gateway
- targets are discovered via service discovery or static configuration
- multiple modes of graphing and dashboarding support

#### Data Model

> Prometheus fundamentally stores all data as time series: streams of
>   timestamped values belonging to the same metric and the same set of
>   labeled dimensions. Besides stored time series, Prometheus may
>   generate temporary derived time series as the result of queries.